# Save button deletes previous data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android studio and firebase. I am trying to save a list of people to firebase like this. Idea is that the logged in user should be able to save information about some people.

```
String userId = user.getCurrentUser().getUid();
databaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("savedPersons").child("name").setValue(nameTxt);
databaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("savedPersons").child("surname").setValue(surnameTxt);
databaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("savedPersons").child("gender").setValue(genderTxt);
databaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("savedPersons").child("ageTxt").setValue(ageTxt);
```

It does not surprise me that it deletes the previous saved person when i save another one but i don't know how to save all of them. I have this in my firebase but i need multiple saved users. How do i do it ?
[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWRqA.png)

Comment: Try looking at [Working with Firebase Realtime Database lists](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Firebase_Realtime_Database_Lists).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "it deletes the previous saved person when i save another one".  It's also not clear what the problem is here - you should describe what is happening that's different than the outcome you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save multiple people in a list in the database, you'll want to call push:

```
String userId = user.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference newRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("savedPersons").push(); // 

newRef.child("name").setValue(nameTxt);
newRef.child("surname").setValue(surnameTxt);
newRef.child("gender").setValue(genderTxt);
newRef.child("ageTxt").setValue(ageTxt);
```

This will create a new child node under `savedPersons` each time you call `push()`. To learn more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [appending data to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

---

Note that calling `setValue` for each property is wasteful, and may lead to unexpected behavior down the line. I recommend putting all values in a map, and then adding them all with one call to `setValue`:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new Map<>();
values.put("name", nameTxt);
values.put("surname", surnameTxt);
values.put("gender", genderTxt);
values.put("ageTxt", ageTxt);
newRef.setValue(values);
```